Suggestions for best method to cut knurled pattern on flat board like in reference photo provided
I'm looking for suggestions on how to achieve the following pattern shown in the following image. Thank you.


Do you mean other than a CNC?

CNC is what I thought would do it but what CNC setup (machine, tooling and type of wood) would be best? Cost wise at least...

I would look for a local Makerspace or something similar, many of them have CNC machines and people willing to teach you how to use them.

What size area are you desiring to engrave?

Around 25cm x 15cm.

Please note that in a woodworking context a texture like this would generally referred to as checkering, not knurling. Now that aside, what's the scale here? When I look at this I think gun handle or gun stock, but I'm sure you want something that's much larger than this as your title says flat board. Both how much of this (total area) and the scale of the 'grid' are key factors — although CNC can do this regardless, it impacts any suggestions of alternative methods.

A simple, non-CNC, solution would be to use a router that slides on a router-sled.
Use a 1" v-bit (example: https://www.acmetools.com/freud-1-in-dia-v-grooving-bit-with-1-2-in-shank-20-112/008925385424.html)
Next step would be to mark the intervals where you want the channels and route on one diagonal, then reset the wood to a consistent width (something like 1").
Turn the wood 90* and route across at the same intervals.
You can probably experiment with other radius bits to get unique effects.

Either use a CNC to carve it for you or a small, sharp chisel and loads of patience.

I'll agree that your best option is CNC, not so sure about the chisel and patience part, but if you do that, you'll have pride of workmanship forever. The makerspace suggestion is also a good one. I've often taken on laser cutting jobs for others, solely for the cost of materials and the ability to use my tools to be of assistance. If you have a similarly populated makerspace nearby, you may be able to engage members, even if the facility lacks the hardware.
In the CNC world, if you don't care for the typical Cartesian X/Y devices, your options would be Origin priced for the low-end models from US$1900 (refurb) to US$2900. It's an interesting visually guided router. One applies tracking tape to the work surface, loads the router with the cut project file and follows the line that appears in the on-router display. The bit "wobbles" as needed to stick to the project, which allows the operator to be less-than-perfect with the handling of the tool.
Another option is the rather large DIY router known as the MakerMade M2 CNC Kit which appears to be a turnkey version of the DIY router known as Maslo. The former is priced at US$998 minus frame, the latter at US$525, also minus frame. No tracking tape required, and for something that can cut a 4' x 8' sheet, impressively takes up little horizontal room, as the work bed is not-quite-vertical.
Far more details are available on the web sites than could be provided here in a practical manner.
